# Use Titanium 3.x without login

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

How can i configure my Titanium Studio for use without login account?

Becouse sometimes i dont have internet.
Does the use mode exist option for without login?

Thanks!!

Comment: No, AFAIK you should have to login to the Appcelerator account to use the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit your project with another external editor and you run it with CLI [Titanium CLI official documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Titanium_Command-Line_Interface_Reference) you can work offline.